# Suitable data structure to store and query integers based on most significant bits

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, hashmap, trie

Given **N** 64-bit unsigned integers I would like to efficient store them in a data-structure **D** and being able to do the following query:

Given an integer **A** return all the Integers in **D** that have the same at least the **k** most significant bits.

If for example with have a list of 3 64-bit integers:

```
a. 1010010000000000010000000000000000000000100000000000000000000001
b. 0000000100001000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000001
c. 1010010100000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000001
```

and query A is:

```
1010010000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000001
```

and we choose k = 7

it should return a list of 2 elements:

```
a.1010010000000000010000000000000000000000100000000000000000000001
c.1010010100000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000001
```

if query A1 is :

```
0010010000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000001
```

and k = 2

it should return a list of one element:

```
b. 0000000100001000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000001
```

if query A2 is :

```
1110010000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000001
```

and k = 3

it should return an empty list.

N size should be in the order of 50 million integers.

Can you point me to the most suitable data-structure?
Also It would be nice if I could insert/delete from the data structure D
after it's creation.

Answer (score 5):

If you think of the integers as strings of bits starting from the most significant bit, you could use a [bitwise trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-fast_trie). A [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) allows you to store key-value pairs, and although in your case you don't actually need to store values associated with each integer, it also allows for efficient searching for all entries starting with a given prefix (i.e. starting with a given k most significant bits). Another option is a [Y-fast trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y-fast_trie).

Comment: maybe Judy array would work (http://judy.sourceforge.net/).
Do you know any y-fast trie pure c++ implementation? Because I saw Judy array API and looks confusing

Comment: I found [this](https://github.com/Akigeor/Y-Fast-Trie) implementation but I haven't used it.

Answer (score 1):

**Using trie:**

Define a *trie-node* and *trie* as

```
struct node{
   node *zero;
   node *one;
   vector <char> index; //Stores the indexes of the numbers which possess such bit pattern
}
```

Zero initialise the *trie* as *root*:

```
node *root = new node;
root->zero = nullptr;
root->one  = nullptr;
```

Follow the insertion technique same as binary tree, going top to down recursively.

After processing first bit, trie would look like:

```
              root

          /          \

   0{np, np, {b}}    1{np, np, {a, c}}
```

After processing 2nd bit, trie would look like:

```
              root

          /          \

   0{np, np, {b}}    1{np, np, {a, c}}
                        /
    /                   
00{np, np, {b}}   10{np, np, {a,c}}
```

Searching method in this trie would be same as binary search tree, with complexity **O(k)** for each query,

where `k <= 64`.

---

Another solution :**Simple and efficient for huge number of queries**

In a given list of integers, different pairs can have different bit patterns of size `k` bits. For example, there can be `4` different bit patterns for size `k=2`, and each bit pattern can have its own list of numbers.

In order to ensure fast processing of queries, we can use `std::unordered_map` and `std::vector`:

```
vector<unordered_map<int, vector<char>>> vecMapForEachBitPos(64);  // for 64-bit integers.
```

Get the first bit (MSB) of each number, put the bitPattern value as `key` in `unordered_map` and put number index (`a./b./c.` in your case) as value.

Repeat the above step for 2nd MSB, 3rd MSB, ... onwards till 64th MSB to get something like this:

```
v[0] = {{0, b}, {1, {a, c}}};

v[1] = {{0, b}, {2, {a, c}}};

v[2] = {{0, b}, {5, {a, c}}};
  ^      ^  ^    ^   ^  ^
  |      |  |    |   |  |
  Bit    |  -----|----------Number index having such bit pattern.
Position |       |
          ----------value of bitpattern till that bit position.
```

After this your problem becomes very simple.

`v[k-1].find(A >> (64-k)).second` stores the list you are looking for. If `v[k-1].find(A >> (64-k)) == v[k-1].end()`, no numbers satisfies the bitpattern, return an empty list as solution.

Search complexity : **O(1)** for each query.